# reCaptcha is making page display incorrect on my browser

Tags: php, css, recaptcha

All,
I have the following two pages.

The first page has a reCaptcha on it and when I view it on my phone it causes a large space on the right hand side (the main grey should align to the right). You can view the link here:
http://tinyurl.com/9hj9y7j

The second page doesn't have the reCaptcha on it and you can see how the page gets displayed with the grey pretty much flush to the right side:
http://tinyurl.com/cm5p4tg

I have the following CSS code to control the reCaptcha:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    #recaptcha_image img {
        width: 250px;
    }
    #recaptcha_image {
        width: 250px;
    }
}
```

I also have the following to control which type of reCaptcha to display depending on if the user is using a mobile browswer or not (http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/):

```
<?php
if ($detect->isMobile()) {
?>
<tr><td valign="top" colspan="2">
<script type="text/javascript">
 var RecaptchaOptions = {
    theme : 'custom',
    custom_theme_widget: 'recaptcha_widget'
 };
</script>

<div id="recaptcha_widget" style="display:none">

   <div id="recaptcha_image"></div>
   <div class="recaptcha_only_if_incorrect_sol" style="color:red">Incorrect please try again</div>

   <span class="recaptcha_only_if_image">Enter the words above:</span><br>
   <span class="recaptcha_only_if_audio">Enter the numbers you hear:</span><br>

   <input type="text" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field" />

   <div><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.reload()">Get another CAPTCHA</a></div>
   <div class="recaptcha_only_if_image"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('audio')">Get an audio CAPTCHA</a></div>
   <div class="recaptcha_only_if_audio"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('image')">Get an image CAPTCHA</a></div>

   <div><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.showhelp()">Help</a></div>

 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=<?php echo $publickey; ?>">
 </script>
 <noscript>
   <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=<?php echo $publickey; ?>"
        height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
   <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
   </textarea>
   <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
        value="manual_challenge">
 </noscript>
 <?php
 }else{
 ?>
 <tr><td width="100" valign="top">Prevent Spam:</td><td>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var RecaptchaOptions = {
    theme : 'white'
 };
</script>
<?php
    echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
 }
 ?>
 <div id="captchaStatus"></div>
<input type="text" value="" name="fill_me_out" id="fill_me_out" /></td></tr>
```

I also have the following code to control the viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Does anyone know why the reCaptcha is causing the page to display differently then when it isn't on there?

I really want to use the reCaptcha to stop spam so need to find a solution to what the issue is.

Thanks!

Comment: Might be worth checking out Akismet (http://akismet.com/). It's also less annoying/intrusive than answering a captcha...

Comment: @TiesonT. Do you have any other suggestions that are free?

Comment: Akismet is relatively cheap for business use, and easy to use. I have a script around here somewhere if you need an example. If you don't/won't have a high volume of input, $5/month is a steal for what you get. Otherwise, no, I don't know of anything better.